# Sass dynamic imports

Tags: sass

This is my code:

```css
@for $i from 1 through 4 {
    @if $i != 3 {
        @import "./wb_app#{$i}/main.scss";
    }
}
```

Which produces this error:

```sh
Error: This at-rule is not allowed here.
   ╷
16 │         @import "./wb_app#{$i}/main.scss";
   │         ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
   ╵
scss\webs\apps\_main.scss 16:9  root stylesheet
scss\main.scss 9:9              root stylesheet
```

Can anybody find me a way to `@import` all the "main" SCSS files from each `wb_app[$1]`?

File-tree:

```
|-- app
|    |-- wb_app1
|    |   `-- _main.scss
|    |-- wb_app2
|    |   `-- _main.scss
|    |-- wb_app3
|    |   `-- (empty)
|    `-- wb_app[$n]
|        `-- _main.scss
`-- all.scss
```

Comment: You can't dynamically import files.

Comment: Ohh ! So, that was the matter.
Thank for the help :)